# GoLang Telegram-bot-api how to ask for location?

Tags: go, telegram, telegram-bot

I am using [github.com/go-telegram-bot-api](https://github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api) to create my bot. I want to ask location of the client. How do I do it? So far I did this:

```
updates, err := bot.GetUpdatesChan(u)

for update := range updates {
    if update.Message == nil {
        continue
    }

    switch update.Message.Text {
    case "/shop":   
        msg := tgbotapi.NewMessage(update.Message.Chat.ID,"Send me your location")
        //I need to make this message ask for the location
        msg.Text = tgbotapi.ChatFindLocation
        bot.Send(msg)
        continue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no examples for this in their repository. I read a bit of their code to figure out how to do it.

This is a sample bot that requests location for every message it got. I created a one button virtual keyboard that shares location when clicked.

```
package main

import (
    "gopkg.in/telegram-bot-api.v4"
    "log"
)

const botToken = "Put your bot token here!"

func main() {
    bot, err := tgbotapi.NewBotAPI(botToken)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    bot.Debug = true
    log.Printf("Authorized on account %s", bot.Self.UserName)

    u := tgbotapi.NewUpdate(0)
    u.Timeout = 60
    updates, err := bot.GetUpdatesChan(u)

    for update := range updates {
        if update.Message == nil {
            continue
        }

        log.Printf("[%s] %s", update.Message.From.UserName, update.Message.Text)

        msg := tgbotapi.NewMessage(update.Message.Chat.ID, "Hi")
        //msg.ReplyToMessageID = update.Message.MessageID
        btn := tgbotapi.KeyboardButton{
            RequestLocation: true,
            Text: "Gimme where u live!!",
        }
        msg.ReplyMarkup = tgbotapi.NewReplyKeyboard([]tgbotapi.KeyboardButton{btn})
        bot.Send(msg)
    }
}
```